# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at using AndEngine Physics Extension

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, andengine

I have used Andengine GLES Version1 and with AndenginePhysicsExtension..

I have recently converted eclipse project to Android Studio and remove all errors and finally run application.

And boom I have got this error..!!

**`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:`**

```
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.spec.friskycatch, PID: 1012
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.spec.friskycatch-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.spec.friskycatch-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so"
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.spec.friskycatch.view.game.FriskyGameActivity.onLoadScene(FriskyGameActivity.java:283)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.spec.friskycatch.view.game.FriskyGameActivity$1.onComplete(FriskyGameActivity.java:263)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.spec.friskycatch.service.sprites.AsyncTaskLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:31)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.spec.friskycatch.service.sprites.AsyncTaskLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:5)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-29 16:04:31.292 1012-1012/com.spec.friskycatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

How to solve it?

Edited : Added build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        // Enable MultiDexing:  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/FLurry_3.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/pixel-perfect-collision.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
    compile project(':zip_file')
    compile project(':andEngine')
    compile project(':downloader_library')
    compile project(':viewPagerLibrary')
    compile project(':com_google_android_vending_licensing')
    compile project(':physics')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}
```

Edited :

Here I am adding file hierarchy of physics extension :

But I did not have any structure like below :

```
|--app:
|--|--src:
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--|--jniLibs
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi
|--|--|--|--|--|—andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.so
|--|--|--|--|--X86
|--|--|--|--|--|--andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.so
```

I have also searched for this file `andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.so` in project but can not find it.

Any help appreciated..!!

Thanks

Comment: Please, add gradle.build file to the question

Comment: @llya : Added gradle file..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post: [HOW TO SETUP ANDENGINE WITH ANDROID STUDIO](http://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/setup-andengine-with-android-studio/). You probably didn't add native libraries of Andengine correctly (libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so)

Remove this part from your gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}
```

Then copy libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so to the jniLib folder. Your folders should be similar to this:

```
|--app:
|--|--src:
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--|--jniLibs
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi
|--|--|--|--|--|—andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.so
|--|--|--|--|--X86
|--|--|--|--|--|--andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.so
...
```

Comment: @llya : Which gradle 'application' or 'physicsextension' ??

Comment: I think application. And you can find *.so files here https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/tree/GLES2/libs

Comment: @AndiGeeky did you succeed with building your app?

Comment: @llya : Nope.. I am creating new application with upgraded andengine and physicsextension..!!

Comment: @llya : Finally solution from link worked..Thanks..!!

Comment: @llya : Can you please edit your answer with full description of how to add physics extension so others can easily do it right away from here so they do not have to look for link..!!